# How to escape the single quotation json running in PowerShell

Tags: json, powershell

I need to create the Body as below but the single quotation mark around ABC gets syntax error when running in PowerShell.

```
    $Body = '{
    “Tag”:"Reference='ABC'"
    }'

    Write-Host -Message "$Body"
```

I tried the below solution:

```
    $MyVar = 'BRO001023'

    $Body = '{
    “Tag”:"Reference=$MyVar"
    }'

    Write-Host -Message "$Body"
```

BUT I got the result as below.

```
    {
    “Filter”:"Reference=$MyVar"
    }
```

How can I make it shows like `{ “TagFilter”:"Reference='ABC'" }`

Answer (score 1):

You can either use a verbatim/single-quoted here-string:

```
$Body = @'
{
    "Tag":"Reference='ABC'"
}
'@
```

Or escape all inline `'`'s by *doubling* them:

```
$Body = '{
    "Tag":"Reference=''ABC''"
}'
```

See the [`about_Quoting_Rules` help topic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_quoting_rules) for more information about quoting rules for different string literals

Comment: Thanks. Problem is sovled as advised.